# on return from json only show value not show data

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, authentication

for login User, I create a modal and when user click on login if user name or password was incorrect return ***SignInStatus.Failure*** it's Ok,
but page refreshed and I have a page with only "3" in top of page without any think

but I want show message on top of the login modal form  ex=`"user name or password is not correct"`,

[image]

**my code in**

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> _LoginPopup(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return PartialView("ModalPopUp");
    }

    // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
    // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
    var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
    switch (result)
    {
        case SignInStatus.Success:
            MigrateShoppingCart(model.Email);
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
            return View("Lockout");
        case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
            return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
        case SignInStatus.Failure:
        default:
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
            return Json(SignInStatus.Failure, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

and my model partial view is

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("_LoginPopup", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
        {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <div id="failorLogin"></div>
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Email" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "password" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RememberMe, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-8" })
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RememberMe)
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RememberMe, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="pull-right col-md-3">
                        <input type="submit" id="btnLogin" value="Login" class="btn btn-default" style="background-color:#5d1338;color:white" />
                    </div>
                </div>

            }
```

**and ajax code is**

```
$("#btnLogin").click(function (e) {
    e.defaultPrevented();
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("../Account/_LoginPopup")',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'json',
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            model:model,
            "__RequestVerificationToken":
                $("input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]").val() 
        },
        success: function(data) {

            alert(data);

        }
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because although you're making the AJAX request, the `<form>` element submission is still happening. This in turn is cancelling the AJAX request (as the page is unloaded) and then redirects to the Partial View. This is why you see the lone `3` in the page.

To fix this issue, hook your event to the `submit` of the `<form>` element and call `preventDefault()`, like this:

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url: this.action,
    type: this.method,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
      model: model,
      "__RequestVerificationToken": $("input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]").val() 
    },
    success: function(data) {
      alert(data);
    }
  }); 
});
```

Note that I used `form` as a selector here, but I'd suggest you use something more specific in your production code. An `id` selector, for example.

Also note that you've specified `dataType: 'json'`, yet most of the logical outcomes from your Action will result in a HTML response.